# Android Change Imageview with Button Click

Tags: android

I am trying to change the background of imageview using the button click. Each button click needs to rotate the background.

Problem : My application code compiles fine but crashes when clicked on the button. Also the log shows the point towards the imageview where we have created instance of it.

How can i find out the issue within the code and

Here's my code for activity.xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.devnami.maya.maya.MainActivity"
> <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/forest"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    /> <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="45dp"
      android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:background="@drawable/flower"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      /> </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my code for activitymain.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton one = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   ImageButton one = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
      ImageView iv =(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.view1)
            int i = 0;
            if (i == 0) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain));
                i++;
            } else if (i == 1) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.seashore3);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.night1);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 3) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.forest);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
     });
```

Note my question is not related to the previously posted questions here on stackoverflow. As what I am trying to accomplish here is changing images of imageview using the buttonclick. This hasn't covered in any previously asked questions.

**Update :** For anyone who is trying to swap the background image using imageview as explained in the question. Please don't do that. There is a lot of memory usage and crashes you have to go through while debugging.

Instead use ImageSwitcher. This allows your view to have fullscreen background. You can choose from array of drawable resources and then just use button to shuffle through.

Comment: hey there .show me the log

Comment: Where is it crashing? Also, you're missing some code from that activity; where are you overriding `onCreate`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your error is here

```
ImageView iv =(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.view1)
```

**this** is not the activity but the onClickListener.
Either extract your **ImageView** to a field or use a field that holds an instance of the activity instance.

Full example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView iv;

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton one = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageButton one = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    iv =(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.view1)
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = 0;
            if (i == 0) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain));
                i++;
            } else if (i == 1) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.seashore3);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.night1);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 3) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.forest);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code with this one,

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       int i = 0;
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ImageButton one = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
ImageButton one = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
 one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView iv =(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.view1);

        if (i == 0) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain));
            i++;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.seashore3);
            i++;
        } else if (i == 2) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.night1);
            i++;
        } else if (i == 3) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.forest);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: I think he would run into the same problem here, see my answer

Comment: no you just created i as a local variable, which won't work.

Comment: If you look again you can see I created it as class field